# How to select specific dimension from .ico Icon

Tags: java, image, icons, .ico

Imported Items from One Server along with the Icons and Description. Icons are in different format i.e. `.jpg`, `.ico`, `.png` etc.

I want to select 64*64 from the `.ico` Icons which have multiple dimensions.

Is this possible with Java Code ? If Yes, any Hint should be helpful.
If No, What is the alternative to get 64*64 size icons from `.ico` format as It contains multiple dimensions. (without using any tool)

Comment: where you want to display this icon. is it a webapp, desktop app or mobile app

Comment: @SangramJadhav : Desktop

Comment: [Image4j](https://github.com/imcdonagh/image4j) supports ico file. License is LGPL. Check their documentation